# NativeScript + Angular2 analytics

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I am trying to use some analytics service with my {N} app.

I succesfully added Angulartics to the app, but don't know how to provide it with my (google analytics) key - there's no index.html, where I could write my key.

I checked Nathan Walker's [seed](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced), but I am failing to see how to configure the analytics service for NativeScript.

There are also plugins for analytics for NativeScript, but they don't seem to be focused on an Angular2 app.

How do I configure and use analytics in my app?

Answer (score 1):

After searching and discussing on NativeScript's Slack I found, that a simple solution does not exist. These are my two options:

- Implement a plugin
- Integrate Firebase

I went with Firebase, since I needed to implement push notifications anyway.